# combining data from multiple tables to excel

Tags: sql, excel

I am trying to get data from multiple tables into one dataset in excel.  I am a beginner sql.

Each table has Patient Number as a unique identifier.

Table 1 may have 1 columns that result in 4 rows of data for any given patient.

Table 2 may have 7 columns that result in 26 rows of data for any given patient.

and so on.  I pull data from 24 tables and it ends up being 61 columns and about 8000 rows.  Problem is, if I try to join all of these tables with the Patient Number, I end up with 10's of thousands of rows returned.

Right now I am just running 24 separate queries, putting the results of each one in a separate tab on my spreadsheet and then running a macro to combine all the tabs into one spreadsheet with 61 columns.

Seems like sql should be able to do this.  But I am a beginner so I am having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: It depends on the tables, their columns, their relationships to each other and the meaning of their data columns.  So you should show us some of that stuff.

Comment: What does your query look like? You could definitely join 24 tables together (I wouldn't encourage it though) in one query and only select the 61 columns you need. The 8000 -> 10k+ rows issue sounds like a situation where you're using the wrong join for the job you need, but again a query to look at would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Question was not exatcly clear, But what I understood is that you need a easy way to save thease data in "sql" to a spreadsheet. I recommend you to use CSV(Comma separated Vlaues) formatting .Because You can easily define the Column headers on your own and it easy to add data to each column and you can foget about the "Tab" thing which is a complex approach.

Use ArrayList to save all pataients Objects.Each and every object in that List will carry all the information for a particular patient ,which fetched from your SQL Database.

[Refer this](http://www.filesculptor.com/csv-file-tutorial/) for more info in CSV
Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got some help with this.

I ended up using a Union All.  The problem with that before was that all my different tables had different numbers of columns and different numbers of rows for my key identifier.  So I can use a Union All if I use Null in my select statements so that I have the same number of columns in all my select statements.  Then the query just stacks all of the data together:

Many thanks to Kris at http://www.essentialsql.com/

I have 19 tables and 62 column, so I have a way to go before I finish the query.

(SELECT PatientID, 1 as TableOrder, A1, A2, NULL as B1, NULL as B2, NULL as C1, NULL as C2
FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT PatientID, 2, NULL, NULL, B1, B2, NULL, NULL
FROM TableB
UNION ALL
SELECT PatientID, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, C1, C2)
ORDER BY PatientID, TableOrder